# Defining variables as undefined in Javascript for readability

Tags: javascript, variables, formatting, refactoring

When defining variables within a Javascript function I'd normally do the following:

```
function test ( param ) {

   var a = param,
       foo,
       bar;

   ...
}
```

Where `foo` and `bar` are defined later in the script.

To make this code fit my ideal formatting rules, it would look as follows:

```
function test ( param ) {

   var a   = param,
       foo = undefined,
       bar = undefined;

   ...
}
```

Are there any reasons not to do this?

I know it seems a little superfluous as the result is exactly the same as far as I'm aware - I think it increases readability. I like to define all my `var`s at the top of each function as I know that's how Javascript interprets them anyway.

Comment: any variable that's not been given a value is undefined by default..and there wouldn't be any reason not to instantiate a variable with undefined.

Answer (score 0):

The better way would be to initialize your variables with `null` instead of `undefined`.
This way you would be able to check out your properties in developer tools (like chrome developer tools), if your variables are not anonymous.

`null` means that variable `exists`, while it does not hold any value, and `undefined` means that variable is not defined - meaning it `does not exist`.